# Can a thyristor regain its forward/reverse blocking capability if the current through it is "instantly" brought to zero?

Tags: switches, high-voltage, semiconductors, thyristor, switching-losses

I am imagining a situation where we have several series-connected thyristors, say 10, each that can block a voltage of 100V.  So, the ten series-connected thyristors together can block a total voltage of 1kV. I am imagining, now, that in series with these series-connected thyristors is a pair of (low-voltage) anti-series IGBTs.

The rest of the circuit ensures that at t = x seconds, the voltage across the thyristors/anti-series IGBTs is zero; however, the current may not be zero.  My question is: Can I use the anti-series IGBTs to instantaneously decay the thyristor current to zero, so that they can nearly instantaneously regain their ability to block bidirectional voltages? Typically, thyristors require a turn-off time, but this is assuming natural decay of the currents through them.  I am wondering if the turn-off time can be significantly reduced if the current through the thyristors can be forced to zero.

Comment: It’s called forced commutation. But the elephant in the room is your series connection. Do not series connect semiconductors unless all other options are ruled out.

Comment: Thanks, winny. This is just a hypothetical situation where I do need to use series-connected thyristors.  Can the turn-off time of the thyristors be improved if I use the anti-series IGBTs to instantly clamp the current to zero?

Comment: Why using series of thyristros instead on single one?

Comment: In fact, why use thyristors if the IGBTs can handle the current and voltage?

Comment: Hi guys, this really isn't the point of my question. We can change the question.   Assume we have one 1kV thyristor in series with a set of anti-series IGBTs, rated for a much lower voltage (say only 10V).  Once the voltage in the circuit is zero, the IGBTs are opened to instantly stop the current through the thyristor. Will this improve the thyristor's turn-off time?

Comment: At the moment the IBGTs turn off the thyristors are still on and full voltage is applied across the IGBTs. I smell smoke.

Comment: Hi Transistor.  The voltage across the thyristor upon turning off would be practically zero, so there would be no smoke.  I am wondering how instantly turning off the free-wheeling current affects the turn-off time of the thyristor.

Comment: OK, so there is something else causing the voltage to drop to zero such as an AC supply. You might want to clarify that in your question.

Comment: Hi, yes, something else in the circuit bring the voltage to zero, as stated in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Turn-off time of a thyristor is of the order of microseconds to hundreds of microseconds depending on the type. That's a long way from instantaneous.

Eg. [this](https://www.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/switching_thyristors/littelfuse_thyristor_sxx40x_datasheet.pdf.pdf) 40A SCR has a tq of 35us.

You can apply a reverse voltage to reverse blocking thyristors (eg. SCRs) to sweep the carriers out more quickly.

Comment: Hi Spehro. Thank you for the response. In the hypothetical case that the current through the thyristor is instantly taken to zero (say for instance there was current of 10A flowing through it, which was instantly taken back to, and held at, 0A, how would the turn off time be affected?

Comment: I think it would be similar to tq (which is specified under a bunch of specific conditions). You can find SPICE models for many thyristors and try it in simulation. For example [here](https://www.littelfuse.com/technical-resources_old/spice-models/thyristor-spice-models.aspx).

Comment: But if the current went instantly to zero, there wouldn't be a chance for the carriers to recombine, would there?

Comment: They will recombine regardless of external current, but I am not sure what the time required would be. My guess is similar to tq.

Answer (score 0):

If the circuit voltage is 0, the only way there can still be current flow is due to inductance in the circuit. In which case, using IGBTs (or any other means) to force the current to 0 will cause an inductive voltage spike, which will probably cause all your semiconductors to break down.

Comment: The idea is that it would be like an LCC, except with anti-series IGBTs in series with the valve. My question (very hypothetical - this would obviously never be done in practice), is whether the anti-series IGBTs, which will break the current and reduce it to essentially zero, will enable the thyristors to turn off. The thyristors would be below their holding current due to the anti-series IGBTs' current breaking. But, would they turn off still within the rated Tq?